# Let $P = \{X \in \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{Z}_{+}) | X \text{ is finite}\}$. Prove that P is denumerable.

Tags: proof-verification

$\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}_+)$ is the power set of the positive integers. I know the general way to prove a set is denumerable is to find a bijective function between that set and the positive integers, but I'm not sure how to write something that does that without assuming $P$ is already denumerable. Can anyone offer a solution?

Comment: It's enough to make an injective function from $P$ into a set that you know is denumerable, for instance into ${\mathbb N}$.

Comment: A standard trick is writing a set as a countable union of countable sets.

Comment: @user275313 I think that leads me into the same problem I'm unable to get past now. Each element of P is a countable set because it is finite. But I'm not sure how to show that the "number" of sets in P is countable.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Why would an injective function alone prove that P is denumerable?

Answer (score 0):

For each set $X$ in $P$, define the "height" of $X$ to be the number of elements in $X$ plus the sum of all elements in $X$.  The height is a positive integer (or $0$ for the empty set) because $X$ is finite.  Moreover, it is not too hard to check that for every positive integer $h$, there are only finitely many sets with height $h$.  Therefore we can list all sets of height $0$, followed by all sets of height $1$ (actually, there aren't any), followed by all sets of height $2$ and so on, thus giving a list of all sets in $P$.  Therefore $P$ is denumerable.

The list might begin
$$\eqalign{
  &\varnothing\,,\ \{1\}\,,\ \{2\}\,,\ \{3\}\,,\ \{1,2\}\,,\ \{4\}\,,\ \{1,3\}\,,\ \{5\}\,,\ \{1,4\}\,,\ \{2,3\}\,,\ \{6\}\cr
  &\color{red}{\,0\ \ \ \ \ \,2\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 3\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 4\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 5\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \,5\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 6\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 6\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 7\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 7\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 7}\cr}$$
where for each set I have also given the height in red.